# JavaScript calculating wrong percentage in two inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, percentage

I have the following inputs:

`cost`, where I type in a currency value, like `6,23`, `profit`, where I type in a percentage value like `29,21` and `value` where the sum of the both values is show.

JavaScript does the math and returns me in `value` the value from `cost` + the currency value of the percentage typed in `profit`, in which case the result is `8,05` (`6,23 + 29,21%`).

But if try to do the same, but informing the `value` instead of `profit`, as the same `8,05`, so JavaScript would return me the `profit` of `29,21`, but it returns me `36,44`.

Does anyone know what it can be?

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".valor").on("input", function () {
        // Margem
        var valor = $(this).val();
        var valorCorrigido = parseFloat(adicionarPontos(valor));
           
        var valorFloat = parseFloat(valorCorrigido) || 0.0;

        // Custo  
        var valorCusto = $('#custo').val();
        var valorCustoCorrigido = parseFloat(removerPontos(valorCusto));
        var valorCustoFloat = parseFloat(valorCustoCorrigido) || 0.0;

        // Calculo
        var calculo = (parseFloat(valorFloat) - parseFloat(valorCustoFloat)) / parseFloat(valorCustoFloat) * 100;
        var inputMargem = $(this).attr("margem");

        $("#" + inputMargem).val(calculo.toFixed(2)).trigger('blur');
    });
    // Faz o calculo do valor com base na margem
    $(".margem").on("input", function () {
        // Margem
        var valorMargem = $(this).val();  
        var valorMargemCorrigido = parseFloat(adicionarPontos(valorMargem));
        var valorMargemFloat = parseFloat(valorMargemCorrigido) || 0.0; 

        // Custo
        var valorCusto = $('#custo').val();
        var valorCustoCorrigido = parseFloat(removerPontos(valorCusto));
        var valorCustoFloat = parseFloat(valorCustoCorrigido) || 0.0; 

        // Cálculo
        var calculo = (parseFloat(valorCustoFloat) * parseFloat(valorMargemFloat) / 100) + parseFloat(valorCustoFloat);
        var inputValor = $(this).attr("valor");

        var resultadoMonetario = calculo.toFixed(2).toString();
        resultadoMonetario = resultadoMonetario.replace(".", ",");

        $("#" + inputValor).val(resultadoMonetario).trigger('blur');
    });

    function removerPontos(valor){
        valor = valor.replace(".","");
        valor = valor.replace(",",".");
        return valor;           
    }
    
    function adicionarPontos(valor){
       if(valor.length == 1){
           return valor;
       }
       else{
       if(valor.length == 2){
           return valor;
       }
       else{

       // The problem was here

       valor = valor.replace(",","");
       var inteiro = valor.substring(0,valor.length - 2);
       var decimal = valor.substr(2);
       return inteiro + "." + decimal;
       }
       }
    }
});

$('input').mask('00.000.000,00', {
    reverse: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.js"></script>


Custo:
<input type='text' id='custo' class='custo valores' name='custo'>
<br>
<br> Valor:
<input type='text' id='valor1' class='valor valores' name='valor1' margem='margem1'> Margem:
<input type='text' id='margem1' class='margem valores' name='margem1' valor="valor1">

<br> Valor:
<input type='text' id='valor2' class='valor valores' name='valor2' margem='margem2'> Margem:
<input type='text' id='margem2' class='margem valores' name='margem2' valor="valor2">
```

Answer (score 1):

The calculations appear to be incorrect because decimal separators in JavaScript are not localized.

```js
6,23 * 29,21 // 21

6.23 * 29.21 // 181.97830000000002

parseFloat(6,23); // 6

parseFloat(6.23); // 6.23
```

You can use [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) or a currency formatting plugin to format the values for display, but your `custo`, `valor`, and `margem` values should be formatted with a `.` decimal separator when you do your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If your total profit equation is `total = cost + (cost * profit)`.

Then your profit % equation should be `profit = (total - cost) / cost`.

Here are two functions that provide you with what you need. You might be interested to use them instead of calculating in line like how you do in your question.

```
function getProfitTotal(cost, profit) {
  cost = parseFloat(cost, 10);
  profit = parseFloat(profit, 10) / 100;

  return cost + (cost * profit);
}

function getProfitMargin(cost, total) {
  cost = parseFloat(cost, 10);
  total = parseFloat(total, 10);

  return (total - cost) / cost * 100;
}
```

Thus `getProfitMargin(6.23, getProfitTotal(6.23, 21.23) );` will output `21.23`. Just use `.toFixed(2)` before setting the value in your text field.

On a side note, you should only reset your field's value if the value is `NaN`. As of now, I am personally unable to write decimals in the example you provided because of this.

Also, all numbers have to be dot-separated. Just parse and format your numbers with a [globalization library](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#number-module), as your current functions are not working correctly as described earlier.

Answer (score 0):

So seems that the problem was in this part of the code:

```
valor = valor.replace(",","");
var inteiro = valor.substring(0,valor.length - 2); 
var decimal = valor.substr(2);
return inteiro + "." + decimal;
```

After changing it to this worked fine:

```
 var inteiro = valor.substring(0,valor.length - 2);
 var decimal = valor.substring(valor.length - 2, valor.length);
```